# Can't access Apache Server through IPv6 from outside

Tags: apache, ubuntu-22.04

My goal is simple : I just want to access my Apache Web server installed on a Ubuntu Server on a local PC behind my box in IPv6.
Using NAT, I can do it with IPv4 but it's a little bit "headache-able" to keep it work with a domain name and SSL. So I tried to make it work with IPv6, the IPv6 of my server is public and I just have to complete the AAAA of the domain name.

The problem is : I searched and tried a lot of things, I learned a lot but the problem is still complete !

The situation :

- Ubuntu server shows the good IPv6 adress when I do *hostname -I*
- I can ping my machine using a external website (*dnschecker* for example) from and outside my local network [DNSchecker capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CTco.png)
- Apache is configured to use IPv6 adresses and serve pages when asked from the local network BUT it does NOT work when accessed from outside (my problem !)
- ufw is configured to use IPv6 tables, allows Apache then Apache Full [ufw status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apwa4.png)
- no firewall on my internet box

I'm dry, I don't know what to look for in order to solve this problem. I need help, thanks for your ideas and advices.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, this question is probably more suited to https://serverfault.com/.  It sounds like your Apache vhost config is probably relevant, you might want to edit to include that.  You should also describe exactly what happens, "does NOT work" does not tell us anything.  There are many related questions on serverfault, have you seen those?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I just posted my question on Serverfault :) Have a nice day !